# How to Copy+Paste text file more 20 MB to Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I tried to expand bin/idea.exe.vmoptions xmx to -Xmx1024m but IDE told me to set more heap space.

Comment: Then set more heap space.

Comment: 1 GB is my PC limit.  Maybe someone has already this problem, cause there are many information about about expand xmx memory dialog in Idea can to search. Maybe resolution is to install svn service and make commit this parent, unoptimized file yet/

Comment: IDE can't start without dialog even though I copy and move file size more then 25 MB to project folder. Maybe text file in IDE project stored in heap memory, and if it is not sufficiently, IDE ask for more heap memory limit (-Xmx1024m)

Comment: Then there is nothing to do. Report a bug.